# jQuery overlay with external page not fading to semi transparent (IE problem?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've used the example external overlay with external page from here http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html to get pretty much what I want. However the example has a nice faded semi transparent background that works in IE and Chrome. My attempt works in Chrome fine but in IE8 it doesn't fade the background. It is white and not transparent at all.

Is there a fix for this? Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Since the flowplayer example do work on IE8 you should post your own code or even better, link to an online version.